# Why does 1 > -1 seem to be false?

Tags: c, char, int

I have written the following the code, but the problem is it is not showing the desired output.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    unsigned x=1;
    signed char y=-1;
    if(x>y)
        printf("x>y\n");
    else
        printf("x<=y\n");

    return 0;
}
```

the above program should output x>y because 1st condition should be true as 1 is greater than -1 but it's giving output x<=y.
why the if condition is not true ?

Comment: The `signed char` operand `y` is converted to `unsigned`, yielding a large positive value.

Comment: if signed char y is converted to unsigned then it should be y=1 and then x==y but when i used condition if(x>=y) the if condition was not true.

Comment: No, the result of converting `-1` to `unsigned` is `UINT_MAX`, not `1`.

Comment: now, got it.
yes, after converting the unsigned char it's a huge number 10 digits.that's why the if condition becomes false..
thanks.

Comment: No. after converting it's not 255.
if i use x=256 it still shows the if condition false.

Comment: -1 in unsigned is MAX_UINT, which is 4294967295 on a 32-bit platform.  You can test this by doing: printf("%u\n", (unsigned)y);  There is no value of x for which x>y is true.

Comment: @thang: It's `UINT_MAX`, not `MAX_UINT`.

Comment: @KhairulBasar, why you conclude that -1 converted to unsigned is +1 ??? -1 converted to unsigned ***is undefined***  what means that compilers are free to do whatever they want with that.  C is a programming language made by programmers for programmers, so is frequent you'll not get even a warning on that.

Comment: just for everybody, -1 in unsigned is undefined behaviour.  Even if all compilers implement it the same way.

Comment: @LuisColorado `(unsigned)-1` is not undefined behaviour. Conversions and assignment from signed to unsigned is well-defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unsigned x=1;` == `unsigned int x=1;`.

and `x = 0x00000001;` `y = 0xff`

when compare between `x` and `y`, there will `type conversion` because types of the two are different.

`y` will first convert to `int`, with value `0xffffffff`, but types of the two are still different, so type of `y` will convert to `unsigned int`, with value `0xffffffff`.

now, comparation between two `unsigned int`, and values are: `x = 0x00000001`, `y = 0xffffffff`. Now, you should understand the reason.

Comment: -1 cannot be converted to unsigned, but is allowed by compilers, producing ***undefined behaviour***... This is a frequent cause of errors.  Better think on the consequences of converting negative numbers to unsigned as undefined behaviour than assume gratuitously that -1 just compares with 0xffffffff (what does happen with 64bit integers, or with short integers?)  What happens in non two's complement arithmetic architectures?

Comment: `y = 0xFF` is not a good way to write things. `y` is `-1` . The representation in memory might be all-bits-set, however (a) that is irrelevant to the question, and (b) when you write `0xFF` it's confusing as to whether you are talking about the representation in memory, or the C integer literal.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Just write `~0` if you want an unsigned with all ones, but don't use `-` sign with unsigned integers.  The reason of `0xff` not being a good value is the dependency to the word length in the architecture.  Ok, there are ways to circunvent this without having to be architecture dependent, but using signs is not one of them.

Answer (score 3):

the program is giving wrong output because of type casting from signed char to unsigned int.
try to avoid char to int implicit type casting.